# What is the difference between $@ and $* in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

in my `script.sh`:

```
aa=$@
bb=$*
echo $aa
echo $bb
```

when running it:

```
 source script.sh a b c d e f g
```

I get:

```
a b c d e f g
a b c d e f g
```

What is the difference between `$@` and `$*` ?

Comment: @mat Why google didn't find all the other duplicates?

Comment: @0x90: Google doesn't index "punctuation", just words; try [symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%24%40+%24%2A) for things like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no difference between `$*` and `$@`, but there is a difference between `"$@"` and `"$*"`.

```
$ cat 1.sh
mkdir "$*"

$ cat 2.sh
mkdir "$@"

$ sh 1.sh a "b c" d

$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor   11 mar 24 10:20 1.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor   11 mar 24 10:20 2.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 igor igor 4096 mar 24 10:21 a b c d
```

We gave three arguments to the script (`a`, `b c` and `d`) but in "$*" they all were merged into one argument `a b c d`.

```
$ sh 2.sh a "b c" d

$ ls -l
total 24
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor   11 mar 24 10:20 1.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 igor igor   11 mar 24 10:20 2.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 igor igor 4096 mar 24 10:21 a
drwxr-xr-x 2 igor igor 4096 mar 24 10:21 a b c d
drwxr-xr-x 2 igor igor 4096 mar 24 10:21 b c
drwxr-xr-x 2 igor igor 4096 mar 24 10:21 d
```

You can see here, that `"$*"` means always one single argument, and `"$@"` contains as many arguments, as the script had. "$@" is a special token which means "wrap each individual argument in quotes". So `a "b c" d` becomes (or rather stays) `"a" "b c" "d"` instead of `"a b c d"` (`"$*"`) or `"a" "b" "c" "d"` (`$@` or `$*`).

Also, I would recommend this beautiful reading on the theme:

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#ARGLIST