# Difference between $@ and $*

Tags: bash, parameters, command-line-interface

I have wrote a simple script that takes in any number of parameters to demonstrate the difference between `$@` and `$*`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                
echo "double quoted $*     $@"
echo 'single quoted $*     $@'
```

On the CLI I did

```
$./stuff.sh a b c d e f dfs
```

And this is what prints out

```
double quoted a b c d e f dfs     a b c d e f dfs
single quoted $*     $@
```

Since they are identical does that mean `$@` equals to `$*`? Or is there a point I am missing?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-the-difference-between-and-in-bash), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967074/difference-between-and-in-bash-scripting), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596826/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-script).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Special Parameters in Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

> *
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word
>   with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of
>   the IFS special variable. That is, "$*" is equivalent to "$1c$2c…",
>   where c is the first character of the value of the IFS variable. If
>   IFS is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces. If IFS is null,
>   the parameters are joined without intervening separators.
>
> @
>
> Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the
>   expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a
>   separate word. That is, "$@" is equivalent to "$1" "$2" …. If the
>   double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the
>   first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original
>   word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last
>   part of the original word. When there are no positional parameters,
>   "$@" and $@ expand to nothing (i.e., they are removed).

Better with an example:

```
$ d=(a b c)
$ for i in "${d[*]}"; do echo $i; done <---- it is a field all together
a b c
$ for i in "${d[@]}"; do echo $i; done <---- each item is a different field
a
b
c
```

Comment: Correct info, but quoting back to a really awful source. (One of the constant annoyances in #bash is helping folks unlearn bugs the ABS taught them to write).

Comment: Precisely I was just looking for a better reference. Updated :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ set -- "hello world" foo bar
$ printf '<%s> ' "$@"; echo
<hello world> <foo> <bar>     # "$@" keeps original separation
$ printf '<%s> ' "$*"; echo
<hello world foo bar>         # "$*" combines everything into one string
$ printf '<%s> ' $*; echo
<hello> <world> <foo> <bar>   # $* (no quotes) loses delimitation entirely.
$ printf '<%s> ' $@; echo
<hello> <world> <foo> <bar>   # unquoted, $@ is identical to unquoted $*.
```

Technically, `$*` isn't limited to space-delimiting; it uses the first character of `$IFS`. This can be used to your advantage:

```
jars=( *.jar )
IFS=:
export CLASSPATH=${jars[*]}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for `$@` (without double quotes) like you did for the others please? Your examples help me to quickly understand the differences.

Comment: When used without quotes, `$@` is exactly identical to `$*` without quotes. I'll gladly add an example to that effect.

Answer (score 3):

From http://linuxsig.org/files/bash_scripting.html:

> $*    Stores all the arguments that were entered on the command line

so

```
$1 $2 ...
```

> "$@"  Stores all the arguments that were entered on the command line, individually quoted

so

```
"$1" "$2" ...
```

Comment: `$1 $2 ...` is only true with the default `IFS` value. If you set `IFS=:`, then it becomes `$1:$2:...` f/e.